# Is every sequence convergent to zero belongs to one of $l_P$ for $p>1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is every sequence convergent to zero belongs to one of $l_P$ for p>1?

i.e Is $c_0\subset\cup_{p>0} l_p$ ?

We know that every $l_p$ sequence is in $c_0$. Now i am looking for converse.

I am not able to prove it?

Also i am not able to find examples.

Comment: By $l_p$, you mean sequences of real numbers $a_n$ such that $\sum  a_n^p$ is finite, right?

Comment: yes.  $\sum|a_n|^p<\infty$

Comment: And your take on this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not correct. Consider for example $a_n=\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$.

Comment: But i am not able to prove that $\sum(\frac{1}{ln(n+1)})^p$ divergent for all p>1

Comment: I got it thank you very much